# Logging from IOS to Papertrail

Tags: ios, paper-trail-gem

Does anyone have a simple way to get the NSLog output from 3rd Party Libraries such as Urban Airship or OpenTok to a remote log server, specifically Papertrail? With our code it is easy, we just use our own log routine that goes to papertrail. Note that these are libraries we do not have source for but for which we believe use NSLog for their various logging levels. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this project, https://github.com/icanzilb/MTLog

It basically redefines NSLog to do what you want. You could probably pair it with https://bitbucket.org/rmonkey/papertraillumberjack/ in some way. Or at least gain some insights from it to do what you want.